# HtmlUnit .setText() throwing a null pointer exception, yet element is not null

Tags: java, htmlunit

So I'm trying to set the text of an element in HtmlUnit but for some reason I dont quite understand an NullPointerException is being thrown. Obviously the element exists on the page and it is found by htmlunit! so why would setText throw an error? Any ideas?

Code:

```
String code = "123";

HtmlTextInput textElem = (HtmlTextInput)page.getHtmlElementById("gc-redemption-input");
System.out.println(textElem);
textElem.setText(code);
```

Output:

```
HtmlTextInput[<input type="text" required="" id="gc-redemption-input" name="claimCode" class="gc-redemption-input a-input-text a-span12 a-form-selected" autofocus="autofocus" value="">]
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.hasTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3241)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:102)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.dom.MutationObserver.attributeReplaced(MutationObserver.java:165)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireHtmlAttributeReplaced(HtmlElement.java:348)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireHtmlAttributeReplaced(HtmlElement.java:353)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireHtmlAttributeReplaced(HtmlElement.java:353)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireHtmlAttributeReplaced(HtmlElement.java:353)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireHtmlAttributeReplaced(HtmlElement.java:353)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireHtmlAttributeReplaced(HtmlElement.java:353)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireHtmlAttributeReplaced(HtmlElement.java:353)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireHtmlAttributeReplaced(HtmlElement.java:353)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireHtmlAttributeReplaced(HtmlElement.java:353)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.setAttributeNS(HtmlElement.java:209)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlInput.setAttributeNS(HtmlInput.java:538)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput.setAttributeNS(HtmlTextInput.java:164)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.setAttribute(DomElement.java:331)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlInput.setValueAttribute(HtmlInput.java:94)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput.setText(HtmlTextInput.java:124)
```

Comment: This should be fixed now. See [Htmlunit null pointer on filling input , but element is not nulled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41839518/htmlunit-null-pointer-on-filling-input-but-element-is-not-nulled)

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be `String code = '123';`, because it shows the following error within my IDE: `Unclosed character literal`. Try double quotes instead: `String code = "123";`.

Comment: Thanks for the good catch! unfortunately that is not the issue, it was one line I didnt copy over and instead typed up :)